# ESP-IDF Standard Toolchain Setup for Linux failed with 6 errors like "ERROR: tool xtensa-esp32-elf has no installed versions."

Tags: esp32, linux-toolchain

I am trying to install ESP-IDF on a freshly created SD-Card (to develop/flash ESP32S3). Following the  official setup instructions fail.

I set up the SD Card with "Raspberry Pi Imager.app" (Bullseye 32-bit or Bookworm 32-bit) with ssh and WiFi enabled.

After booting the new card on a Raspberry Pi 4, the following steps from [the official ESPRESSIF site](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/get-started/linux-macos-setup.html): (the first two steps are not part of the official instructions but are necessary to keep the Linux up to date)

```
 sudo apt update
 sudo apt upgrade
 sudo apt-get install git wget flex bison gperf python3 python3-pip python3-venv cmake ninja-build ccache libffi-dev libssl-dev dfu-util libusb-1.0-0
 mkdir -p ~/esp
 cd ~/esp
 git clone --recursive https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf.git
 cd ~/esp/esp-idf
 ./install.sh esp32,esp32s3
 . $HOME/esp/esp-idf/export.sh
```

I get:

```
WARNING: directory for tool xtensa-esp-elf-gdb version 12.1_20221002 is present, but tool was not found
ERROR: tool xtensa-esp-elf-gdb has no installed versions. Please run '/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/esp/esp-idf/tools/idf_tools.py install' to install it.
WARNING: directory for tool xtensa-esp32-elf version esp-12.2.0_20230208 is present, but tool was not found
ERROR: tool xtensa-esp32-elf has no installed versions. Please run '/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/esp/esp-idf/tools/idf_tools.py install' to install it.
WARNING: directory for tool xtensa-esp32s3-elf version esp-12.2.0_20230208 is present, but tool was not found
ERROR: tool xtensa-esp32s3-elf has no installed versions. Please run '/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/esp/esp-idf/tools/idf_tools.py install' to install it.
WARNING: directory for tool riscv32-esp-elf version esp-12.2.0_20230208 is present, but tool was not found
ERROR: tool riscv32-esp-elf has no installed versions. Please run '/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/esp/esp-idf/tools/idf_tools.py install' to install it.
WARNING: directory for tool esp32ulp-elf version 2.35_20220830 is present, but tool was not found
ERROR: tool esp32ulp-elf has no installed versions. Please run '/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/esp/esp-idf/tools/idf_tools.py install' to install it.
WARNING: directory for tool openocd-esp32 version v0.12.0-esp32-20230419 is present, but tool was not found
ERROR: tool openocd-esp32 has no installed versions. Please run '/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/esp/esp-idf/tools/idf_tools.py install' to install it.
```

and cannot progress further. I can't be the only person seeing this but I cannot find any web-based advice. Can anyone help me get past this (please)?

Comment: By default the GCC tools should be installed in `$HOME/.espressif/tools`.  Do you see this folder? Also search for a tool: `locate xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc`, does this show anything? Could perhaps be a permission problem.